# Concatenating multiple columns using condition in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate multiple columns bases on condition. Data is as follows.

```
CRN Diff    Pay1    Pay2    Pay3    Pay4    Pay5    Pay6    Pay7    Pay8    Pay9    Pay10
1   1   000 084 084 084 000 XXX 000 XXX XXX XXX
2   10  065 000 000 000 000 XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX
3   -1  000 XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX
4   3   XXX 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
5   -2  070 070 070 070 070 070 070 XXX XXX XXX
6   1   090 XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX
```

The code I am using is as follows.

```
data temp;
set temp;
format hist $200.;
array col(*) Pay1-Pay10;
if diff=-1 then hist=catx('',col(2-10));
else if diff=-2 then hist=catx('',col(3-10));
else hist=catx('',col(*));
run;
```

I want concatenate column based on diff=-1 , -2 etc and concat corresponding columns.

The error I am getting is "array subscript out of range". Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array definition does not allow the use of either -8 or -7 as an index.  Only integers between 1 and 10.  But it does not look like you need to define or use an array at all.

Just use variable lists instead. Make sure to use the `OF` keyword when passing a list of variables to a function.

```
if diff=-1 then hist=catx(' ',of pay2-pay10);
else if diff=-2 then hist=catx(' ',of pay3-pay10);
else hist=catx(' ',of pay1-pay10);
```

Comment: @Tushar, to clarify `-8` and `-7`  the expression `col(2-10)` would refer array element `col(-8)` which is the cause of *array subscript out of range*.  SAS arrays allow any integer range for indexing but the default `(*)` starts at `1`.  `Col(2-10)` does not mean col(2) through col(10) as you might have presumed.  Per @Tom, just use the variable list syntax to supply `catx` it's arguments.